# Cisco router - edit or view file content in telnet

Tags: cisco, router

Is there a command for editing (or at least viewing) text file content (that is on flash card) ?

Comment: Which text file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Cisco IOS, you've got the **more** command, like on Linux, which you can use to print the content of a file.

> The more command shows a text file. This command works just like it does in Linux—it allows youto view a file on a disk. In the case of the Cisco IOS, you can use this command to view a text file, such as your configuration file or a saved backup configuration file. Here's an example:
>
> Router# more nvram:startup-config

Answer (score 5):

It is also possible to create a file with TCL scripting:

```
Router#tclsh
Router(tcl)#puts [open "flash:test" w+] {
+>This is a test.
+>Line 2.
+>Third line.
+>}

Router(tcl)#tclquit

Router#more flash:test
This is a test.
Line 2.
Third line.
```

I'm not a TCL expert, but I think editing is also possible by using the `a+` (append) open flag instead of `w+`, and `append` instead of `puts`.